# Camel Apache: Cannot rename file with header value

Tags: apache, apache-camel, filenames

I'm having a *txt* file with some *ids*. 
For every id, I'm trying to make some **GET** requests on an endpoint (url) and to get the response as a JSON file and put it into a folder with a specific name for every file.

Everything is fine, I've made the requests, I get the JSON file for every id, I can put them into a folder with some dynamic name.

But when I'm trying to rename the files with their ids, something like **jsonFile_234**.txt a Camel Exception is throwing.

*org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: 
Cannot store file: src\main\resources\jsonFromGetReq\mandatJson_690
.txt*

This is how my camel route looks like.

```
<camel:route id="makeRequestForEachId">
    <camel:from uri="file:src/main/resources/idList?noop=true" />

    <camel:split>
        <camel:tokenize token="\n" />
        <camel:to uri="stream:out" />

        <camel:setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <camel:constant>GET</camel:constant>
        </camel:setHeader>

         <camel:setHeader headerName="manId">
            <camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple>
        </camel:setHeader> 

        <camel:recipientList>
            <camel:simple>
                http://examples.com/${header.manId}
            </camel:simple>
        </camel:recipientList>

         <camel:to uri="file:src/main/resources/jsonFromGetReq/?fileName=json_${header.manId}.txt&amp;fileExist=Move&amp;moveExisting=${file:name.noext}_${date:now:MMddyyyy-HH_mm_ss}.txt"></camel:to>

    </camel:split>
</camel:route>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem without getting any more exceptions?

Comment: Maybe you have not the permission to write files to this folder.

Comment: when I'm trying to rename that file otherwise than with the header.manId, let's say ${header.CamelHttpMethod} or ${header.CamelSplitIndex} everythings works like a joy.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of my problem.
When Camel makes the split with the token "\n", he make my id looks like id\n and when I write ${header.mandatId} the value of this expression is *id\n*.

And the file will have a name like: 
json_32(**new line** */n*).txt

And this file, with new line in name, cannot be created.

```
<camel:tokenize token="\r\n" />
```

This solved my problem.